# PyTorch: Dynamically freeze layers in my network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I have a network and I want to only update the first few layers' weights. The thing is, I want to change the amount of layers I update dynamically through the training process.

Is there a way to do this without having to change each weight to trainable = False? (or requires_grad = False)

Comment: What is the problem with setting `requires_grad=False` during the training loop?

Comment: Because this would require me to do so for every weight in every layer, and I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do so.